# Logical expression in key of dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

As a simplified example, say I have the following if statement

```
if x > 5:
    score = 1
else if x <= 5
    score = 2
```

How can I replace this with a dictionary? I want something like

```
score = {x > 5: 1, x <= 5: 2}[x]
```

My actual if statement is quite long, so I'd like to use this condensed construct.

Comment: You'd have to rebuild the dictionary every time, and only end up with two keys; the first version is more readable and likely to be more efficient.

Comment: A dictionary maps keys to values. Unless you know the value of `x` is somehow constrained to some enumerable set of values, then you cannot build a dictionary that will be equivalent to your `if-else` statement. Regardless, you should just stick to the `if-else` construction. Which expresses the intent plainly and efficiently.

Comment: BTW, you can't do `else if` in Python. The correct syntax is `elif`. OTOH, there's also the ternary expression, eg `score = 1 if x > 5 else 2`.

Comment: it looks like a job for `filter` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using if-else will be the most readable solution. Also it avoids the problem that you would need an infinite amount of values to express something like `x > 5` with a dictionary (as it will map all number starting from 6).

Only if you know that the domain is limited (e.g., x is always less than 1000), it will work. The simple if statement will most likely be faster.

To express ranges, you can use this short notation:

```
if 4 <= x <= 10:
  ...
```

If you have a very complicate formula (lots of if-else statements), and a limited number of values, using a precomputed table makes sense, though. This is what compilers also do if they have to translate complicated switch-case statements in C like languages when the values are dense. They implement it as a lookup table.

I would still recommend to start with writing the formula as if-else statements, and then use a function that computes the dictionary based on the if-else code and the range of possible values. To fill the dictionary, iterate over the range of possible values:

```
def score(x):
  if x > 5:
    return 1
  elif x <= 5:
    return 2
  ...

d = dict((i,foo(i)) for i in range(1,100))
d[x]
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll just stick with the if-else as you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a dictionary, you can use a list of tuples, where one item is a function and the other is a value. You loop through the list, calling each function; when the function returns a truthy value you return the corresponding value.

```
def greater_than_5(x):
    return x > 5
def less_or_equal_5(x):
    return x <= 5

scores = [(greater_than_5, 1), (less_or_equal_5, 2)]
for f, val in scores:
    if f(x):
        score = val
        break
```